# ixgbe: increase rx performance

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

I have an Intel 82598EB 10GBE NIC.

I need to receive traffic without packet loss.

Data rate is 4-5 Gbps, packet size is 1500-9600 bytes.

I had already configured smb and irq affinity.
I also tried to use packets socket ( PF_PACKET ).

None of this helped. Small losses is always present.

Now I am planning to compile kernel with disabling any configuration settings that increase the size of sk_buff and disabling IOMMU.

What are other ways to improve rx performance?

Comment: Have you already increased net.ipv4.tcp_rmem ? Also you may look at the different congestion algorithms available, its possible the default algorithm isn't suited for the network that's connected to that interface.

Comment: You might also try to experiment with using ethtool to see what offload functions your NIC supports and which ones seem to increase performance.

Comment: During the day I was changing driver settings, and network subsystems settings. Just an hour ago found that only net.core.rmem_default has affect ( I am use UDP ). I regret that I did not read your post earlier. :)

Answer (score 0):

NAPIs can help you, as well as TSO, GSO, UFO, can help you if your ixgbe support the TSO option but anyways GSO should be supported, ethtool can be useful in setting them on, and make sure you have the ethtool_ops registered in the driver, otherwise they wont work out.